# Issues trying to write a custom htaccess url

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on a project and i want to write a custom htaccess rule for something like

mysite.com/productname without it intefering with my site files or directories

I have tried

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

 RewriteCond ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php -f

 RewriteRule product_detail.php?detail=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have URL's such as `mysite.com/productname`, then you should be able to just use this.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+) product_detail.php?detail=$1 [NC,L]
```